# Hovered modal not getting positioned properly

Tags: javascript, css, sass, flexbox, tailwind-css

So basically this is calander and there are 30 boxes(calendarBox) representing each date of a month. So when I hover over any box then the eventDetails modal should up
I applied the CSS to achieve that but for some reason the position absolute is featured with respect to a global div and is placed at a fixed place, instead with relative to calendarbox. I don't understand why.
Want I want to achieve is that when I hover over any box then the modal should show up right below the box.
Please help me understand whats happening here?

Note: Both are sibling divs

```
function getHoveredEventDetails() {
    const formattedDay = day.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    let matchingDates = [];
  
    eventsCountandDate.forEach((event) => {
      if (event.date === formattedDay) {
        matchingDates.push(event);
      }
    });
    if (matchingDates.length > 0) {
      return matchingDates.map((event, index) => {
        const coursesDetails = event.courses;
        return coursesDetails.map((course, courseIndex) => {
          return (
            <div className="profile" key={`${index}-${courseIndex}`}>
              {console.log(course.courseName)}
              <h1 className="profile_title">{course.courseName}</h1>
              <p className="profile_para">On {course.startProgramDates} till {course.endProgramDates}, From {course.startTime} to {course.endTime}</p>
            </div>      
          )
        });
      });
    }
  }

return (
    <>
      <div className={`border border-gray-200 flex flex-col calendarbox ${getCurrentDayClass()} ${hasEventsOnDay}`}>
        {rowIdx === 0 && (
            <p className="text-sm text-slate-950 day text-center bg-personal">
              {day.format("ddd").toUpperCase()}
            </p>
        )}
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <p className={`text-base p-1 my-1 text-center`}>{day.format("DD")}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 cursor-pointer" 
             onClick={()=> {
              setDaySelected(day);
              handleShowEventModal(day.format("DD-MM-YYYY")
              )}}
        >
          {getDetails()}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="eventDetails"> 
        {getHoveredEventDetails()}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

```
.calendarbox {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #fff4e4;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  min-width: 120px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 120px;
  transition: 3000ms; 
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20rem;
  z-index: 0;
}

.eventDetails{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;  
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%; 
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  background-color: #313131e8;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out; */
  transition-delay: 3s;
  z-index: 2000;

}

.calendarbox:hover + .eventDetails{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  display: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  /* z-index: 20000; */
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code for the variables/functions that are missing definitions used in your example please?

Comment: The `.eventDetails` div is outside of the `.calendarbox` div, so it is positioned relative to the next element with position relative or the body. Try moving that whole div up one line to nest it in the calendarbox.